# How to replicate a pimcore instance to another over network

Tags: replication, master-slave, pimcore

I need to replicate from one read/write Pimcore instance to another Pimcore instance read-only.

Is there a smarter way to achieve that than 
- replicating the database (master slave model)
- "rsync"ing the media and class file system folders?

There are APIs to export and import contents and structure, but is this reliable with high volumes ?

Thanks

Comment: Has anyone used RestImporter/RestExporter on big product database ?

Comment: So you forgot to mention that you have access to the pimcore-partner repos. Those do the things I mentioned in my answer, but I have not tested them until now.

Answer (score 0):

Possibility 1:

Never tried this, but you could post the object / asset / ...  to an controller on the other instance. To do that, you need to extend the save-function of all objects or hook into the save event.

On the "slave" instance, you can then check if an object / asset...  with this path and key exists, then update, otherwise create a new.

Possibility 2:

Do it with polling: Instance A tells B about it's objects, ... via a controller. B then iterates and clones it.